# SQL Server condition based concatenation of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider a table holding data like below,

```
COL1|   COL2|   active_flag
----|   ----|   ------------
1   |   A   |   Y
1   |   B   |   Y
1   |   C   |   Y
1   |   D   |   N
1   |   E   |   N
2   |   M   |   Y
2   |   N   |   Y
2   |   O   |   N
2   |   P   |   Y
2   |   Q   |   Y
```

and I require the output like below.

```
COL1|   COL2
----|   -----
1   |   ABC
1   |   D
1   |   E
2   |   MN
2   |   O
2   |   PQ
```

How to achieve this in `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: Post what you have done first

Comment: This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Do you have any sequence column like date or identity in that original table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should add column to `id` to get stable sort. Then you could calculate each group and then concatenate using `FOR XML`:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN 
         LAG(active_flag) OVER(ORDER BY id)  <> active_flag
         OR LAG(active_flag) OVER(ORDER BY id) = 'N' AND active_flag = 'N' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     b  END as l
    FROM t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(l) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS grp
    FROM cte
)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, (SELECT '' + col2
              FROM cte2
              WHERE grp = c.grp
              ORDER BY id
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS col2
FROM cte2 c;
```

**[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/RPQY77408)**

Output:

[image]

Warning!

`ORDER BY 1/0` or `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` do not provide stable sort.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked fine, I have 1 more column along with col1 to get the uniqueness.